# I am surprised that the "Is my pay fair" question was removed from the forum

Tags: discussion

I think it was a genuine question that a lot of QA Engineers (novice & experienced) come across.  Especially for young and/or novice engineers, some of the answers give a very good perspective.

It falls into the lines of "What QA conferences are recommended" OR "what to ask while interviewing a QA", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the message after the moderation system flagged it.

In hindsight I agree this was not correct as, if anything it should have been closed as too localised. Please note that the moderation view only shows the question  ... not the answers or comments in the default view. Looking through that lens, it seemed inappropriate.

That was my mistake, so I have re-instated it.

Generally though, questions should be less "localised", i.e. what is fair in one country will be unfair in another... i.e. someone complaining about a US wage has little relevance to someone in Manilla, India or China.

The question should have more general value to the audience, although the topic itself was fine IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I no longer remember, but I may have been the person who flagged this one.  I thought it was too localized.  The question is surely interesting to the person who wrote it, and it is good that others care enough to offer advice.  However, StackExchange is about questions there are applicable to more than one party.  I thought the way it was worded was so specific that no one else would find it valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Given that issues of `career advice, salary or compensation` are not excluded by [the FAQs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/faq) on this site, then (as accepted by Bruce) deletion may have been premature.

However, as I've just added to the [What should our FAQ contain?](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-faq-contain) thread, I would suggest that such questions SHOULD be off-topic - they are (IMHO) too localized (probably to just the questioner) to be of general interest

Answer (score 0):

I agree, what happened? The person was looking for guidance, maybe he didn't ask it in a approprate way?

Comment: Good question, asked inappropriately, and itchy moderator trigger finger.

Comment: Thanks for the update Bruce.